# reducing memory consumption tensorflow frozen model

Tags: python, memory, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

used the tutorial code to figure out the memory savings using checkpoint files vs a frozen model(.pb files). The theory (and the implementation afaik) is that checkpoint files have a lot of variables that are used during training a model while the frozen model converts them into constants (weights and biases) and hence the memory consumption must be lower. But when i compare the memory consumption there is a difference of about only 50 MB ( 660 MB vs 610 MB). I wonder then, what is the use of freezing a model? Because anywhichways, while serving the model, the size in the memory isn't very different vis a vis recreating the model from the checkpoint files. Posting some code below where i took the measurements ..not sure if the code might give the entire picture but it is totally inspired by https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/translate/translate.py (decode method)

kindly note, the code below is for the version where i am loading the frozen graph, creating input data and straightaway invoke run. I am also trying to identify at which point the memory is blowing up and its evident from the output that it is after `session.run`. Any pointers on what else i could do to cut down memory consumption ? my final model would involve at least a few more models of this nature running together. Thanks a ton !

```
def decode_NER():
    graph = load_graph( 'save/NER_SAVE/frozen_model.pb' )
    for op in graph.get_operations():
       print(op.name)
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/encoder0:0')
    z = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/encoder1:0')
    x1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/encoder2:0')
    z1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/encoder3:0')
    z2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/encoder4:0')
    z3 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/decoder0:0')
    z4 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/decoder1:0')
    z5 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/decoder2:0')
    z6 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/decoder3:0')
    z7 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/decoder4:0')
    z8 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/decoder5:0')
    z9 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/decoder6:0')
    z10 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/decoder7:0')
    z11 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/decoder8:0')
    z12 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/decoder9:0')
    y = [graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection/BiasAdd:0') ,graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection_1/BiasAdd:0'), graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection_2/BiasAdd:0'), graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection_3/BiasAdd:0'), graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection_4/BiasAdd:0'), graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection_5/BiasAdd:0'), graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection_6/BiasAdd:0'), graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection_7/BiasAdd:0'), graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection_8/BiasAdd:0'), graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection_9/BiasAdd:0') ]
   with tf.Session( graph=graph  ) as sess:
    ...........
       while sentence:
           killer = sentence.split(' ')
           from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
           vik = pos_tag( word_tokenize(sentence)  )
           poss = ''
           for wd, tag in vik:
               poss += tag+' '
           token_ids = data_utils.sentence_to_token_ids(tf.compat.as_bytes( poss ), en_vocab)
           print('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
           print( subprocess.run(['free', '-mh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) )
           print( sys.getsizeof( sess ) )
  # Which bucket does it belong to?
           bucket_id = len(_buckets) - 1
           for i, bucket in enumerate(_buckets):
               if bucket[0] >= len(token_ids):
                   bucket_id = i
               break
               else:
                   logging.warning("Sentence truncated: %s", sentence)

  # Get a 1-element batch to feed the sentence to the model.
           encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, target_weights = loc_get_batch(
                  {bucket_id: [(token_ids, [])]}, bucket_id)

           print( encoder_inputs )
           output_logits = sess.run(y,  feed_dict={
        x: encoder_inputs[0], z: encoder_inputs[1], x1: encoder_inputs[2], z1: encoder_inputs[3], z2: encoder_inputs[4], z3: decoder_inputs[0], z4: decoder_inputs[1], z5: decoder_inputs[2], z6: decoder_inputs[3], z7: decoder_inputs[4], z8: decoder_inputs[5], z9: decoder_inputs[6], z10: decoder_inputs[7], z11: decoder_inputs[8], z12: decoder_inputs[9]
           } )
  # This is a greedy decoder - outputs are just argmaxes of output_logits.
           print('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
           print( subprocess.run(['free', '-mh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) )
           print( sys.getsizeof( sess ) )
           outputs = [int(np.argmax(logit, axis=1)) for logit in output_logits]
           print(outputs)
```